# Detect that the "Complete action using" window is showing

Tags: android, android-intent

is there a way to detect when the system displays a "Complete action using" window in Android? These windows appear when launching an `ACTION_VIEW` intent with a maps URI for instance, and you have several navigation apps installed.

I checked and the process on top when this happens is `android`, so cannot really use that.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, No ! Imagine the havoc if that's possible reliably.

Comment: why would that wreck havoc? It's not what I want to do :-)

Comment: Your intentions might be clear but if there are reliable ways to do this, there are many malware authors out there ready to take inappropriate advantage of it like when the window appears, take user to some other Activity etc etc.

Comment: I see your point... I'll wait a bit, maybe a god hacker will come up with an answer